# Spring Framework No qualifying bean of type MessageSourceAccessor JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this exception in my spring framework app. The application is annotation configured. I do not understand why the MessageSourceAccessor can not be autowired. If some code need please notify me. Hope that someone will help.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bg.abv.saas.admin.manager.DomainManager bg.abv.saas.admin.controller.HomeController.domainManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao bg.abv.saas.admin.manager.DomainManager.domainsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainsDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bg.abv.saas.admin.manager.DomainManager bg.abv.saas.admin.controller.HomeController.domainManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao bg.abv.saas.admin.manager.DomainManager.domainsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainsDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao bg.abv.saas.admin.manager.DomainManager.domainsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainsDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao bg.abv.saas.admin.manager.DomainManager.domainsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainsDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainsDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor bg.abv.saas.admin.dao.DomainsDao.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 50 more
```

**EDIT:**

```
 @Import({ JdbcConfig.class, Log4jConfig.class })
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc // Enable Spring MVC
    @ComponentScan("bg.abv") 
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
            return resolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("configure");
            messageSource.setBasename("log4j");
            messageSource.setBasename("sql");
            messageSource.setBasename("strings");
            return messageSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor() {
            return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource());
        }



        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }
```

**DispatcherServletApplicationInitializer**

```
@Repository
public class DispatcherServletApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/app/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        String servletName = getServletName();
        Assert.hasLength(servletName, "getServletName() may not return empty or null");

        WebApplicationContext servletAppContext = createServletApplicationContext();
        Assert.notNull(servletAppContext, "createServletApplicationContext() did not return an application "
                + "context for servlet [" + servletName + "]");

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);

        // throw NoHandlerFoundException to Controller
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet(servletName, dispatcherServlet);
        Assert.notNull(registration, "Failed to register servlet with name '" + servletName + "'."
                + "Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.");

        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping(getServletMappings());
        registration.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSupported());

        Filter[] filters = getServletFilters();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(filters)) {
            for (Filter filter : filters) {
                registerServletFilter(servletContext, filter);
            }
        }

        customizeRegistration(registration);
    }

}
```

**jdbc config and log4j config**

```
@Configuration
    @ComponentScan("bg.abv")
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class JdbcConfig {

        @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
            dataSource.setUsername("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("root");
            return dataSource;
        }
    }

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("bg.abv")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Log4jConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsoleAppender consoleAppender() {
        ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        consoleAppender.setThreshold(Level.ALL);
        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout.setConversionPattern("%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n");
        consoleAppender.setLayout(patternLayout);
        return consoleAppender;
    }

    @Bean
    public FileAppender fileAppender() {
        RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
        fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.ALL);
        fileAppender.setFile("build.log");
        fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("100KB");
        fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(1);
        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout.setConversionPattern("%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n");
        fileAppender.setLayout(patternLayout);
        return fileAppender;
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger registerSpringLogger() {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.springframework");
        logger.addAppender(consoleAppender());
        return logger;
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger registerLogger() {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("bg.abv");
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logger.addAppender(consoleAppender());
        logger.addAppender(fileAppender());
        return logger;
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger registerJdbcLogger() {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("jdbc.sqlonly");
        logger.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        logger.addAppender(consoleAppender());
        logger.addAppender(fileAppender());
        return logger;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you defined this bean somewhere on your configuration? Would be helpful if you can add your configuration into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Error here is quite explicit.

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

somehow you don't have this bean in your context.

Either you forgot to define this bean in your context, or you referring it from other context.

Comment: MessageSourceAccessor is a class from spring lib. How to define it as a bean. I use anotation configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your code to create the bean required for autowiring :

```
@Bean
public MessageSourceAccessor createMessageSourceAccessor() {
    return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource());
}
```

Comment: where have you added ?

Comment: I added it in WebConfig

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the configuration for `org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor`

which can be defined using java configuration as

```
@Bean
public MessageSourceAccessor getMessageSourceAccessor() {
  return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource());
}
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() { 
     ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
     messageSource.setBasename("/path/to/properties/file");
     return messageSource;
}
```

There should be a property file or such for this to work out.

*EDIT*

```
The basenames follow ResourceBundle conventions: essentially, 
a fully-qualified classpath location. 
If it doesn't contain a package qualifier 
(such as org.mypackage), it will be resolved from the classpath root. 
Note  
that the JDK's standard ResourceBundle treats dots as package separators:  
This means that "test.theme" is effectively equivalent to "test/theme".
```

Refer [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasenames-java.lang.String...-) for the usage of bean names.

Comment: `messageSource.setBasename("configure");
                messageSource.setBasename("log4j");
                messageSource.setBasename("sql");
                messageSource.setBasename("strings");` What does this mean ? Please check the edit section

Comment: This are the names of the property files which are in src/main/resources directory. The project is using Maven. I read some documentation and i understand that property files must be in that directory.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes, the property files have to be in the directory of resources. multiple times assigning the basename will override by the last def . Use setBaseNames method instead, as in edit section

Comment: I edited the code like this - messageSource.setBasenames("configure", "log4j", "sql", "strings"); But have the same exception. I think the problem comes from that spring can not initialize MessageSourceAccessor bean but i do not know why.

Comment: Can you add `JdbcConfig.class, Log4jConfig.class ` as well ? It starts with `@Import` is what I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106360/discussion-between-vinayveluri-and-rockordead).